# How can I find the IPs of introduction points for a hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, relays, ip-address

I was wondering if it is possible to find the IPs of introduction points used by a hidden service. Specifically I was looking at facebook's hidden service.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these in the service's hidden service descriptor document. Tor clients download these documents when a user wants to connect to a specific onion service, but you can also download these manually using the [`HSFETCH` command](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=7424472d21725077f83aa9ff19e64ae530798d27#n1608) with Tor's control port. The Stem library [provides a Python interface](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.get_hidden_service_descriptor) to do this, but claims that only v2 services are supported (I'm not sure if the documentation is just out of date). After sending this `HSFETCH` command, tor will return a [`HS_DESC_CONTENT` event](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=7424472d21725077f83aa9ff19e64ae530798d27#n3567) containing the introduction points.